# Intellij Idea console issue

Tags: java, intellij-idea, консоль

Здравствуйте! На днях переустановил свою ОСь Ubuntu и заодно решил сразу установить java 9, но первая же неприятность встретила меня в Idea, при простой печати в консоль мне в первой строке кидает, как я понял, vm arguments. Как мне исправить такую неприятность?
Они не должны выводиться в таком виде, обычно выводится только $JAVA_HOME, остальная часть скрыта.
Вот [ссылка](https://imgur.com/6WXV3wU)!